# Пропали скрипты подключенные Google sites

Tags: google-search

По непонятной для меня причине пропали подключенные скрипты к гугл сайту (управление сайтом -> скрипты -> Скрипты не найдены). Сам проект есть и развернут. кто уже с таким сталкивался, как быть в этой ситуации. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой, ошибка передана разработчикам
https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/sites/GzCU3YzkdQY;context-place=forum/sites